What is the correct way to give the Path of a locally given font to be used for the title of a document (xelatex)
I use the solution given in How can I change the font size of the title and the font size of the authors in Latex? to have the font size of the title as big as possible.
But how to precise the Path if the font is not installed on the system (such is the case overleaf).
Usually I put the ttf font in a folder "fonts", I tried the following without success:
\font\myfont="./font/Times New Roman" at 100pt
\font\myfont="./font/Times New Roman.ttf" at 100pt
\font\myfont="font/Times New Roman" at 100pt
\font\myfont="font/Times New Roman.ttf" at 100pt

The following document should be complied with xelatex.
\documentstyle{article}
\font\myfont="Times New Roman" at 100pt
\title{\myfont Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}



Never use the \font primitive in latex, you should not have formatting in the argument of title at all:  the formatting should be in the definition of maketitle, but for a one-off it will work.
Just replace \myfont with  \timesfont\fontsize{3cm}{4cm}\selectfont where \timesfont is defined by \usepackage{fontspec}\newfontfamily\timesfont{Times New Roman}

Thank you. I just used Times New Roman for simplicity. The font could be not installed system-wide (especially for overleaf). The emphasis of the question was to give the Path to the true type font file. How to modify your answer in order to precise the Path to ttf file?

use \newfontfamily[Path=/some/path.to.the/directory/with/the/font,  Extension= .otf]{fontfile} @Name

+1 Thank you again. It could be helpful for the users if you could provide a complete document using the code you provided.

@Name well the complete version using Times New Roman works on overleaf as shown. I don't have an overleaf projet with a non standard font to show.
